# How to configure OpenVPN for AWS VPC Peering with single private in 1st and single subnet in 2nd VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, openvpn, aws-vpc

I've just installed OpenVPN from AMI Marketplace in my account and connected via LDAP to AWS Simple AD. To start with, here are the details below:

`Bastion Host VPC
Name: Bastion-VPC ---> Has single public subnet
VPC ID: vpc-01000000000000000
CIDR: 10.236.76.192/26`

`Private Host VPC
Name: Private-Environment-VPC ---> Has single private subnet
VPC ID: vpc-02000000000000000
CIDR: 192.168.96.0/20`

I've established VPC Peering between both subnets. Whenever I logon to any machine in `Bastion-VPC`, I can RDP to any machine in `Private-Environment-VPC` machines.

I've installed OpenVPN in `Bastion-VPC` and can normally RDP to any machines inside `Bastion-VPC`, but can't RDP / connect to any machines in `Private-Environment-VPC`.

I'd like to resolve above problem - establish VPC connection to `Bastion-VPC` and RDP to machines in `Private-Environment-VPC` using OpenVPN.

Did tried to follow steps noted at: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=570840 and https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect, but of no help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After trying N number of solutions available, here is the problem:

**1 -** My OpenVPN was joined to AWS Simple AD

**2 -** There was no known way to allow access to all authenticated users to be connected to the private subnet hosted in other VPC

#### Solution

Add permissions for each user in "Allow To" Section for User Profile to allow access to private subnet hosted in other VPC.

Comment: Does this mean that you successfully connect to  OpenVPN server in VPC A, and from there you can access accounts in VPC B through VPC Peering? I have the same goal and am curious if this is possible. (Lots of answers, like that of kenlukas', seems to indicate that it is not possible, but I do not understand the terminology well enough to be sure.)